# Is there any way to replace built-in parametric variable name in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Matrix([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

b = sp.Matrix([35,0,0])

c = a.gauss_jordan_solve(b)

print(c[0][0])
print(c[0][1])
print(c[0][2])
```

**Output:**

```
-tau0 - tau1 + 35

tau0

tau1
```

I want to replace `tau0` and `tau1` with any letter, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use [`eval`](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/eval/) and pass in a string of syntactically correct Python with your parametric variables, have it evaluated and executed by the interpreter.

Comment: `eval` should be an absolute last resort.

Comment: Unfortunately, that appears to be the case, as `'tau'` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/70381f282f2d9d039da860e391fe51649df2779d/sympy/matrices/matrices.py#L3480) into the definition of `gauss_jordan_solve`.

Comment: You might be able to rebuild `c` along the lines of the code that uses `tau` to build `c` in the first place, but I don't know `sympy` well enough to tack such a venture.

Comment: Maybe you could override [`numbered_symbols`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/70381f282f2d9d039da860e391fe51649df2779d/sympy/utilities/iterables.py#L625). This is a generator returning numbered names that will eventually be used as free variables. I don't know `sympy` that well, so I can't vouch for this not breaking something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `isympy` session where `x` and `y` have already been defined as symbols:

```
In [22]: sol, params = a.gauss_jordan_solve(b)                                                            

In [23]: sol                                                                                              
Out[23]: 
⎡-τ₀ - τ₁ + 35⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢     τ₀      ⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣     τ₁      ⎦

In [24]: params                                                                                           
Out[24]: 
⎡τ₀⎤
⎢  ⎥
⎣τ₁⎦

In [25]: sol.replace(params[0], x).replace(params[1], y)                                                  
Out[25]: 
⎡-x - y + 35⎤
⎢           ⎥
⎢     x     ⎥
⎢           ⎥
⎣     y     ⎦
```

`sol` and `params` are `sympy.Matrix` objects.  The `taus` are `sympy.Symbol`.

or drawing from the `gauss_jordan_solve` docs:

```
In [74]: sol.xreplace({params[0]:x, params[1]:y})                                                         
Out[74]: 
⎡-x - y + 35⎤
⎢           ⎥
⎢     x     ⎥
⎢           ⎥
⎣     y     ⎦
```

the code that generates these `tau` names:

```
    # Free parameters
    # what are current unnumbered free symbol names?
    name = _uniquely_named_symbol('tau', aug,
        compare=lambda i: str(i).rstrip('1234567890')).name
    gen = numbered_symbols(name)
    tau = Matrix([next(gen) for k in range((col - rank)*B_cols)]).reshape(
        col - rank, B_cols)
```